# initializing a tree in c

Tags: c, tree, undefined-behavior, null-pointer, memory-access

im trying to initialize a tree data structure but everytime i invoke initTree(); my program terminates without any output my initTree():

```
Tree* initTree(){
Tree* tree = (Tree*) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
tree->root = NULL;
tree->root->left = NULL;
tree->root->right = NULL;
tree->height = 0;
return tree;
}
```

however when i remove the 2 lines `tree->root->left = NULL;` and `tree->root->right = NULL;`
my program works fine , is there any explanation??

Answer (score 3):

The function invokes undefined behavior because there is used a null pointer

```
tree->root = NULL;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to access memory in these statements

```
tree->root->left = NULL;
^^^^^^^^^^
tree->root->right = NULL;
^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is the pointer `tree->root` does not point to a valid object. Thus the two statements above do not make a sense and should be removed.

You may not use a null pointer to access memory.